# Pointwise/Uniform Convergence of a function

Tags: convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Let $f_n(x)$=$nx ,\space \space x\in[0,\dfrac{1}{n}]\brace 0, \space\space x\in(\dfrac{1}{n},1]$. 
Find the pointwise limit of $(f_n)$ and check if $(f_n)$ is uniformly convergent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence converges to 0 everywhere, but the convergence is only pointwise. To prove pointwise convergence, fix $x$. If $x$ is zero, all $f_n$ vanish on $x$, otherwise there exists an index $n$ from which all $f_n$ are zero on $x$, meaning that $f_n(x)=0$ for all $x$, if $n$ is big enough (how big depends on $x$)\

The convergence is not uniform though: uniform convergence means that for given $\epsilon$ there exists an index $n$ from which $f_n(x)<\epsilon$, for all $x$ in the domain. However, we see that when $\epsilon<1$ this does not happen, as $f_n(1/n)$ is always one.

Comment: I am having problem in proving that the function is pointwise convergent to 0. I am guessing that the pointwise limit is 0 but I can't prove that. However, once I have realized that the pointwise limit is 0, it is easy to see that the function is not uniformly convergent.

Comment: A standard technique to prove pointwise convergence is to fix a point $x$, and consider the sequence (of real numbers!) $(f_n(x))$. In the case above, if $x$ is 0 you see that $f_n(x)=0$ for all $n$, hence it converges to 0, if $x$ is different from 0 there exists an N, (namely, every N bigger than 1/x) so that $f_n(x)=0$ for all n>N. Once again, the sequence goes to 0

Answer (score 2):

**Key Ideas**

1. The pointwise limit is clear.
2. To consider uniform convergence, consider the value of $f_n \left( \frac{1}{n} \right)$ for each $n$.

Comment: Sorry but I am stuck on finding the pointwise limit itself. I guess the limit is $0$ but how is it $0$, I need to rigorously prove.

Comment: For any number $x \in (0,1)$, you can explicitly write down an $n$ such that $f_N(x) = 0$ for all $N > n$, namely any $n$ larger than $1/x$.